# Managed Memory C#

Tags: list, memory-management, dump, memory-footprint

I'm running VS2013 to analyze a dump of my application looking for large objects in memory. So far so good, I'm able to identify which are the objects that use memory.

Now, one question, I see one of my list objects (List) that stores ushort data of images, and then I see the actual Uint16 object down below with almost the same size.

See the screen shoot...

Does that means my object uses "double memory"??[image]

Comment: Have you called `ToArray()` on the list?

Comment: No, I haven't called ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. The third number in the list is the size including children. Since the `List<UInt16>` internally uses an `UInt16[]`, and the shown one is probably the referenced one, this is not using double memory.